# React query invalidation is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, invalidation, react-query

How do I invalidate data after refreshing the page? It doesn't seem to invalidate while it is supposed to. It still displays the old data even though something changed on the server-side.

I have this same problem when I use useMutation when posting data to the backend, the UI doesn't update even after using the `QueryClient`.

Below is my code:

```ts
const IncomeManager: React.FC<any> = (props) => {

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    const {isLoading, isError, isFetching, data}: QueryObserverResult = useQuery('typeIncomes', () => typesApi.getAllTypes());

    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

    //@ts-ignore
    const handleClose = (): void => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    }

    const refreshContent = async () => {
        await queryClient.invalidateQueries('typeIncomes');
        console.log("Content has been refreshed!!!");
    }


    return (
        <View style={style.container}>

            <View>
                <AppText style={style.title}>{data ? data.length : 0} income types available</AppText>
            </View>

            <FixedButton
                title={"plus"}
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(navConstants.ADDTYPE, {type: "incomes"})}
            />

            {
                 isLoading || isFetching ? <PageActivityIndicator visible={isLoading || isFetching}/> :
                    <FlatList style={{width: "100%"}}
                              data={data}
                              renderItem={
                                  ({item}) => <CategoryItem
                                      id={item.type_id}
                                      title={item.title}
                                      subTitle={item.description}
                                      onLongPress={() => console.log("Very long press!")}
                                      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(navConstants.EDITTYPE,
                                          {
                                              item: {
                                                  id: item.type_id,
                                                  title: item.title,
                                                  description: item.description
                                              }
                                          })
                                      }
                                  />
                              }
                              keyExtractor={item => item.type_id}
                              refreshing={refresh}
                              onRefresh={async () => refreshContent()}
                    />
            }
        </View>
    );

}

export default IncomeManager;

const style = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: constants.COLORS.secondary,
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    title: {
        color: constant.COLORS.lightGray,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        fontSize: 17,
        marginBottom: 0
    },

});
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the state and effect hooks. You can set data with the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook and with the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook you can add code you want to run when the state(data) updates.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new QueryClient every time your component renders by doing:

`const queryClient = new QueryClient()`

The queryClient holds your cache, which holds your data. There should be only one (like a redux store) - the one you create initially and then pass to the QueryClientProvider. To retrieve this Singleton instance, you can do:

`const queryClient = useQueryClient()`

it will give you the instance via React context. Invalidation on *that* queryClient should work. This is also how everything in the docs and all the example are set up.

Comment: Thanks for helping, the problem has been solved by following your guide.